# What does $ \prod_{i = 2}^{ n-1} \frac{1}{i}$ converge to?

Tags: products

What does $ \prod_{i = 2}^{ n-1} \frac{1}{i}$ converge to?

It boils down to $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{4} * ... * \frac{1}{n-1}$

But is there a direct formula that gives me the same answer?

Comment: multiplication.

Comment: subtraction ...

Comment: There is a more compact notation for this. You can use the definition of the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial): $n! \equiv n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot 3\cdot 2 \cdot 1$ to write $\prod_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the squeeze theorem

$$0\le \prod_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac1i=\frac1{(n-1)!}\le \frac1{n-1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
we get easily the result.

Comment: If I change $i$ to $i^2$ how does it affect the infinite product (i.. $ \prod_{i = 2}^{ n-1} \frac{1}{i^2}$) ?